# Ignore tabs and line breaks in user input using getline

Tags: c++, getline, istream, removing-whitespace

I'm writing a program that takes user input using `getline`(I must use `getline`) and spits it back out to the screen. It is also supposed to ask again if the input was blank. I'm having trouble with handling input that has multiple line breaks and tabs.

I've gotten it to almost work but it's looping through a few times and I can't figure out how to fix it/do it better. Here's the code:

```
string name;

while(true) 
{
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;

    getline(cin, name, '\n');
    if (!name.empty()) 
    {
        break;
    }
}
cout << "Hello " << name << "!" << endl;

return 0;
```

Here's the input:

```
\n
\n
John\n
Doe\n
```

The output I want is supposed to look like this:

```
What is your name?
Hello John Doe!
```

My output looks like this:

```
What is your name?
What is your name?
What is your name?
Hello John!
```

Comment: `'\n'` is the default delimiter of `std::getline()` anyways.

Comment: As for your question: Why not writing another loop to collect the inputs?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that, how would it collect the input?

Comment: And a edited it to match what the output is, thanks!

Comment: First you need to specify a criteria, to determine when the name is completed. Your edit still isn't accurate.

Comment: Edited it again, and I'll give that a shot and see where I get

Comment: By ignoring "line breaks" do you mean newline `'\n'`? That makes your requirement for using `std::getline()` interesting.

Comment: @Justin Yes that is what I mean, it's part of a homework assignment where I am required to use `std::getline()`

Comment: @Sean I think I understand what you want to do.  Check my answer below. I'll be happy to further explain it if needed.  I try to avoid "forever" loops like `while (true)` unless absolutely necessary.  It makes you start thinking of ways to `break` out instead of simply meeting your condition expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible I don't understand your requirements, but if all you want to do is to collect a first and last name from the user on separate lines (while ignoring any tabs), you can do it like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
    while (first.empty())
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, first);
        // remove all tabs from input
        first.erase(std::remove(first.begin(), first.end(), '\t'), first.end());
    }
    while (last.empty())
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, last);
        // remove all tabs from input
        last.erase(std::remove(last.begin(), last.end(), '\t'), last.end());
    }
    std::string name = first + " " + last;
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Your user will be allowed to hit return/enter and tab until they are delirious. Until `std::getline()` gets some non-tabbed input it doesn't matter how many newlines or tabs happen. From your question this seems like what you want.  You can find more information on the STL algorithm that I used to remove tabs with `std::remove` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).